# Pandas DataFrame with multiple repeating columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has the same title in multiple columns. So when I print `df.columns` I get `title.1` `title.2`,`title.3`...etc.
What I m trying to do is to get the highest value of title and rename that column to remove the number and put it into another dataframe.

For example i have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path_from_db, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1)
```

In my case the  most recent values of `title` will be in the last 12 columns of this dataframe. i get that by,

```
df2 = df.iloc[:, -12:]
```

My problem is that `df2` will have the highest value of `title` example `title.7`. how do I remove the `.X` from `title` in `df2`?

Comment: Highest value along row? The row-wise max `df.iloc[:, -12:]` gives you a Series so you can trivially make that a DataFrame with the proper name: `df.iloc[:, -12:].max().to_frame('title')` (or `.filter(like='title')` to select the columns)

Comment: thanks for having a look. I appreciate the help. In my case `df2 = df.iloc[:, -12:]` gives me a series of columns that i am interested in. I make a new df from this series. the problem is that this new dataframe contains "title.X". what i want to do is remove the .X from the new dataframe if possible.

Comment: What about `df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace(r"\.(.+)$", "", regex=True)`?